# Connect to website with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-7, connection

I'm developing a project for windows phone 7. It's very simple I guess but I don't know very well C# especially C# for wp7.

I have an existing php page with this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $ssid=$_GET['name'];
}
$name .= "Hello";
?>
```

I want to make a wp7 application where I can write a name in text, press the button to connect to server, pass the name in the text as php parameter and write server response in another text on mobile screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an HttpWebRequest with your query :

private void MyMethod(Action action){

```
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://website/page.php?name={0}",name));
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse((callBack)=>{
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callBack.AsyncState;
                                    WebResponse webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(callBack);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string response = string.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            response = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            response = ex.Message;
                        }
                        action.Invoke(response);

                    }
webResponse.Close();

            },webRequest)
```

}
where textresponse is your server response

Comment: just another question, how can i return the string textResponse? The return string.empty or return string textResponse doesn't work

Comment: Yes because you are in an anonymous method.
So you need to raise an event, or pass an action, callback to your method and then raise it with the response. I'll edit the code

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

[POST Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Try this (read the first comment tho... author made a typo):

[Post Request](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/)

Comment: im no c# programmer... but... whats the error? Can you do like printErrorStackTrace or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it helps you

in first page or form,

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Projectname;component/pagename.xaml?name=" + variable1 + "&country="+variable2, UriKind.Relative));

in second page or form,

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)

{

```
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string myname = NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];
        string Mycountry = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["country"]);
```

}

The 'name' and 'country' in OnNavigatedTo are same as navigateservice

In this way you send values from one page to another page.